# CI with github Nodejs CI action fails unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, github-actions

After I have set up my GitHub workflow: [Nodejs CI](https://github.com/scicave/math-parser/actions/runs/459025786). I have encountered unexpected behaviour: `ReferenceError: expect is not defined`, for the repo: [math-parser](https://github.com/scicave/math-parser).

[image: fails - node@12]

---

At the same time, when GitHub CI tests using jest and `Nodejs@12` and `Nodejs@14`, everything goes as expected.

Also when testing using `Nodejs@10` in my local machine, all tests are passed.

```
### OS
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic

### Node, npm, npx 
❯ nvm --version
0.35.3

❯ npm --version
6.14.8

❯ node --version
v10.23.0
```

Here is my YAML config `./.github/workflow/tests.yml`:

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    name: tests

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ['ubuntu-latest', 'windows-latest', 'macos-latest']
        node: ['10.13', '12.13', '14.15']

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ matrix.node }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install # not `ci` to make use of the cached node_module

      - name: Build -- Development
        run: npm run build

      - name: Tests
        run: npm run test:ci
```

---

The problem is specifically related to `ReferenceError: expect is not defined`.

I don't think it is an issue with my setup.
If you have a solution or know what is the reason behind this behaviour, please, let me know.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Can you please rephrase your question to include a [mcve] instead of linking to your repo?

Comment: I think my description is quite minimal, I tested using jest in my local machine with the same node version and everything seems good. When it is pushed to GitHub, it failed.

Comment: You should definitely include the workflow definition (YAML) and probably a minimal jest test.

Comment: @riQQ I have rephrased my description, take a look.